# Open source battery charged alarm app for Android?

Tags: android

Can anyone recommend me an open source app that features a battery charged alarm, ideally with a threshold to set?

Like, shoot me an alarm when battery charging reaches 85% of full capacity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Safe Charger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gpa.safecharge)** promises to do exactly that:

> Safe charger is an utility application which alerts you when the battery level reaches a particular range. Note: It will not alert you exactly at 85%. (85 to 95)

*Safe Charger* is open source, you can find it at [Github](https://github.com/AswinChand97/SafeCharger) (and also [in my repo](https://android.izzysoft.de/repo/apk/com.gpa.safecharge)).

If you prefer to set your own value, take a look at **[Battery Charge Notifier](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.utopi.batterychargenotifier):**

> Light weight app that notifies user at user defined battery levels to either charge the device, or to unplug and stop charging. This helps in observing the 40-80 rule of Li-ion batteries.

To my knowledge, *Battery Charge Notifier* is **not** open source, so it does not fully meet your requirements.

If your device is rooted, there's a third candidate to mention: **[Battery Charge Limit](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.slash.batterychargelimit)**. This app again is open source, available at [Github](https://github.com/sriharshaarangi/BatteryChargeLimit) and also [at F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/packages/com.slash.batterychargelimit/), but wasn't updated since 2018. It takes the whole game one level further, not just notifying you but automatically stop charging at the specified battery level.

Full fledged control is given with **[AccA](https://f-droid.org/packages/com.slash.batterychargelimit/)** ([Github](https://github.com/MatteCarra/AccA)), which not only takes care to stop charging, but also pick up charging again when a lower margin (say 70%) is reached – and even can shutdown the device at a low threshold (say, when battery is down to 5%). Again, this app will need root. Being open source, it's available at F-Droid (which is where the link goes to), but not e.g. on Google Play.